# Is this a correct solution? Jordan form of a marix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

I am given a matrix $A$ that is defined the following way:

the element in row $i$ and column $j$ is $\alpha$ if $i=j$, $1$ if $j=i+2$ and $0$ otherwise.

I need to find Jordan Form. This is my solution, I feel like this is too simple so I want to check if I understand it right:

calculating the characteristic polynomial we get that $\alpha$ is the only eigenvalue, therefore the elements in jordan form on the diagonal are all $\alpha$, so the jordan form in the $i,j$ place is $\alpha$ if $i=j$, $1$ if $i = j+1$ and otherwise $0$.

Is the solution fully correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. One example of such a matrix is$$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&0&1\\0&\alpha&0\\0&0&\alpha\end{bmatrix}$$and you are claiming that its Jordan normal form is$$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&1&0\\0&\alpha&1\\0&0&\alpha\end{bmatrix},$$whereas it actually is$$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&0&0\\0&\alpha&1\\0&0&\alpha\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks. How can I solve this problem then?

Comment: Using the fact that, if $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$, then $e_1$ and $e_2$ are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\alpha$ and that $A.e_n=\alpha e_n+e_{n-2}$, $A.e_{n-1}=e_{n-1}+\alpha e_{n-3}$ and so on. Actually, you will have *two* Jordan blocks.